# C# agsxmpp Domain vs connectionserver

Tags: xmpp

I need to establish a connection with the following data:

```
Protocol: XMPP
Username: <Your username>
Password: AIR_<Your LoL password>
Domain: pvp.net
Connection security: Use old-style SSL
Connect port: 5223
```

**connection server: chat.euw1.lol.riotgames.com**

I only managed to connect to a **normal** domain server in this form:

**username@domain.com/resource**

However, I need to add somehow the connectionserver (chat.euw1.lol.riotgames.com).

I really hope someone is familiar with agsXMPP and can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Alright I was just confused, maybe it was just too late for exploring new libs.

However, if someone stucks like me on connecting, here is a easy solution on how to test a login with this library:

```
            XmppClientConnection xmpp = new XmppClientConnection("pvp.net");
        xmpp.UseSSL = true;
        xmpp.Port = 5223;
        xmpp.ConnectServer = "chat.euw1.lol.riotgames.com";
        xmpp.Open("username", "AIR_password");

        xmpp.OnLogin += delegate(object o) { MessageBox.Show("logged in"); };
```